# How to configure Thymeleaf template location

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to use Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot 2.1.5 based application. But I do not need it to create html output for a `RestController`. Instead of that I want it to create html files that the application can store on disk.

Because of this I create two beans `templateResolver` and `templateEngine` like the [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html) describe. The templates are stored in the same location I would use for the `RestController`: `src/main/resources/templates`. One for example is called `index.html`.

But no matter which path I configure (with or without `classpath`) I get the same error message:

```
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/resources/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [resources/templates/index.html] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist

How do I need to configure the path to make it work a) inside STS and b) inside the created jar ?

An alternative to solving this problem would be using `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` instead and "grabbing" its generated output instead of exposing it via the embedded Tomcat but I do not know how to get this to work:

```
@GetMapping("/noneedforthis")
public String getIndexFileContent(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve? Serving static HTML pages?

Comment: No, I want to create dynamic pages based on multiple templates. But the result should be put into a file directly and not be delivered via a webserver. I need to store those files in an archive and keep them for some years.

Comment: That's no problem. Simply read the docs: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: I read the Spring specific Thymeleaf docs but am left with the problem mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I checked both the local `target` directory of my Eclipse workspace and the jar created by running maven install: instead of `resources/templates` the templates are stored in `templates`.

Shortening the path in my code helped and now Thymeleaf can find the templates.

Using the Spring Boot Starter for Thymeleaf would still be an interesting alternative but so far I have not found an approach.